# mod-rewrite redirect child URL to parrent URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in .htaccess I would like to chop off anything after the 2nd '/'… so http://www.domain.com/parent/child/otherchild would be redirected to http://www.domain.com/parent/

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.+$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
```

---

Not sure what you meant by pasting all that unreadable code in the comments, but you want to add exclusion conditions like I mentioned in my comments:

```
AddType application/octet-stream vcf

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.+$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/themes/myTheme/style.css
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This line is an exclusion, because of the `!`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js)$ [NC]
```

That means if the URI ends with `.css` or `.js` then **don't** apply the rule. You can add others as needed. Say you don't want to redirect a URI like: `/foo/bar/no-redirect/`, then also add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/bar/no-redirect/
```

Comment: This works for the client side urls but breaks my links to css / js / etc - Thoughts?

Comment: I guess my question at this point is how to do the above solution for all but specific paths?

Comment: @user2913260 You can exclude specific paths by adding this condition (or any number of them) right before the `RewriteRule`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/some/path/file.css`, you can do that for each path or file that you don't want to redirect.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-content/themes/myTheme/style.css

Comment: @user2913260 can't read code you paste in comments, it's all gibberish

Comment: sorry about the gibberish - I was adding the markdown and StackO wasnt recognizing... So, what I thought would be a fairly straight forward solution actually became a fairly comprehensive view into how htaccess with mod-rewrite works and what it effects. In the end I slightly modified this to include the image formats > RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|json|gif|jpg|png)$ [NC]

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]+/).+$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How can I change it to target only URL's in a specific directory? So that `http://example.com/dir/subdir` would stay as it is, but `http://example.com/redir/subdir` would redirect to `http://example.com/redir/?something=subdir`.